# SELECT Statement does not work when column ID is inserted after WHERE statement

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am trying to filter out only facebook data from a list by Selecting a column and filtering using WHERE statement. I also want the numbers related to that row.

Here is my query

=SORT(query(G1:H4000, "SELECT H, G WHERE G LIKE '%facebook.com%'" , 1),2,FALSE)

This works, but the column H comes before G. I want it after G. When I rewrite my query, I get Value error

Here is my query
=SORT(query(G1:H4000, "SELECT G WHERE G LIKE '%facebook.com%', H" , 1),2,FALSE)

Please see attached image. Not sure why I get this value error.

[image: query]
[image: query]

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap around how you select your data.

```
=SORT(query(G1:H4000, "SELECT G, H WHERE G LIKE '%facebook.com%'" , 1),2,FALSE)
```

Comment: awesome, it works, but can you  explain why it does not work when I entered H at the end. Should WHERE come at last of the query statement?

Comment: H doesnt work at the end because Its not valid SQL. You need to select from the DB the columns in the correct order. WHERE is a key word that comes near the end, but its not the last. I suggest having a look at some SQL tutorials

Comment: sure will do...Thank you for your help and explanation.